# How do you get data from a page with Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I started learning Next.js and got the below working without the "use client" for the "non beta not using the app directory". I then later figured I should just learn it since Next is moving towards implementing new features. I just want some data to display on the home page, but now I get an undefined is not valid JSON and the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0. However, when I go to localhost:3000/api/quotes I see the data.

api/quotes/rout.ts

```
import { Quotes } from "@/app/models/quotes";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const response = await fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes");
  const quotesResponse: Quotes = await response.json();

  return NextResponse.json(quotesResponse);
}
```

page.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Quotes } from "./models/quotes";

export default function Home() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState<Quotes>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getQuotes = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/quotes");

      const quotesResponse: Quotes = await response.json();
      setQuotes(quotesResponse);
    };

    getQuotes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(quotes)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the HTTP GET request is failing, you can verify this by either looking at the logs, network tab in developer console in your browser, or by adding some debug logging such as by changing

```
const response = await fetch("/api/quotes");

const quotesResponse: Quotes = await response.json();
```

into

```
const response = await fetch("/api/quotes");

console.log(await response.text());
```

Then you can verify if the response's body is a valid JSON object or not.